# jackson2.2.0 can not work on android2.2

Tags: jackson, android-2.2-froyo

When using jackson2.2.0 on android2.2(API8), I got this error:

**Could not find class `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentNavigableMap`, referenced from method `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory.<clinit>`**

I've tested my code on android2.3.3(API10) and android4.0.3(API15), it both works.

Does any one knows how to fix this? Or I have to use another jason parser instead.

Answer (score 2):

This has already been reported on Jackson's [issue tracker](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/216). A fix is due in 2.2.2 next week or so.